# Mobile Safari Not Showing My Video Texture

Tags: reactjs, three.js, mobile-safari, react-three-fiber

I have a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68110692/threejs-problem-with-videotextures-on-macos) one, but in my case, it's iOS causing troubles (not macOS, which I haven't tried yet), so I hope it's OK to post this as well.  I tried to create a video texture in Three.js and can't bring it to work on mobile Safari (iOS 15.4).  Here is my code, which I tried to tidy up as much as possible:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";

import "./styles.css";

const Screen = () => {
  const meshRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const vid = document.createElement("video");
    vid.src = "/test.mp4";
    vid.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    vid.loop = vid.muted = vid.playsInline = true;
    vid.play();
    meshRef.current.material.map = new THREE.VideoTexture(vid);
  });
  return (
    <mesh ref={meshRef}>
      <planeGeometry attach="geometry" />
    </mesh>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas camera={{ fov: 25 }}>
      <Screen />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong here.  The `test.mp4` is from [this URL](https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4).  I also tried to place the video as HTML element, instead of creating it dynamically, then the video itself plays fine, but not the video texture.

Also, just curious, but why isn't `meshRef.current` available in a `useEffect` in the main component, but `useEffect` inside of `Screen`, which is placed inside of `Canvas`, is OK?

Comment: I put your test.mp4 url in my vid texture and it also didn't work. My problem is the vid texture works fine on laptop but not on the mobile phone with chrome or safari. Can't reproduce using mobile phone simulator on laptop.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I totally forgot about this question.  I solved it, had nothing to do with the video format but with the hosting, maybe CORS headers or something related.  Will add an answer tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a problem with video file formats.  Tried an example video from Three.js and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To those of you looking for the solution , you need to add

```
vid.playsInline=true;
```

for mobile ios devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to set the 'playsinline' attribute in a very specific way.

`video.playsinline= true` did not work but `video.setAttribute('playsinline', true)`
did work.

Hope this helps